# Microsoft Excel rating computation

Tags: vba, excel, computation

I work in oDesk, and I recently found out how the rating is computed. I made a personal worksheet for myself to keep track of my record. However, the formula I use is too long, and I was wondering on how to shorten it.

The formula is:

(sum of total cash earned multiplied by rating, respectively) divided by (sum of total cash earned)

Let's say I have two columns here:

Column A (total cash earned) - Column B (rating)

$4.50 - 4.80

$5.33 - 5.00

$27.00 - 4.00

My Excel formula is:

```
=((A1*B1)+(A2*B2)+(A3*B3))/(SUM(A1:A3))
```

Is there a way to shorten it, and possibly accommodate future entries without having to edit the formula?

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(Sounds like code golf.) This is four characters (only) shorter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A3,B1:B3)/SUM(A1:A3)
```

but may be more readily extendible.

Or eight characters shorter but perhaps less easy to read:

```
=(A1*B1+A2*B2+A3*B3)/SUM(A1:A3)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
  A1       B1       C1         D1      E1
  $4.50    4.80     =A1*B1             =SUM(C:C)/SUM(A:A)
  ...
  ...
```

or using "pnuts" idea here is an option, which is more easy to maintain that will
 "accommodate future entries without having to edit the formula":

```
  A1       B1       C1         
  $4.50    4.80     =SUMPRODUCT(A:A*B:B)/SUM(A:A)  
  ...
```

Please run a few tests (I have not used SUMPRODUCT much in my life).